# How can I create a custom OpenOffice / LibreOffice Writer table AutoFormat scheme?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

None of the basic table AutoFormat schemes in LibreOffice Writer have both an alternation style defined and no sum column/row style defined.  If they have alternation, they always seem to have sums.  Because of this I'd like to define my own table scheme.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

A WYSIWYG isn't totally necessary.  I am not scared of editing simple XML files as long as I have examples to work from, and if I don't have to edit *base install* files.  If I can place them in a custom area or my user profile directory then that would be best.

If there is a way to get the GUI `Add` functionality to properly recognize an alternation then that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No XML is necessary, it's just not obvious. Open up **Calc** and format some cells just the way that you want the new **AutoFormat** theme to look. Select everything (Ctrl+a or Edit | Select All) and then choose **Format** | **AutoFormat** and click the **Add** button.

If you go to use **AutoFormat** from the **Format** menu in **Writer** afterward, your new style should be listed there.

Comment: There's no  AutoFormat in the Format menu, neither a Format entry in the context menu in LO 4.3.5

Answer (score -1):

From the LibO 3.5 getting started guide (calc section):

---

Defining a new AutoFormat

You can define a new AutoFormat that is available to all spreadsheets.

1. Format a sheet (in the style for the new AutoFormat).
2. Choose Edit > Select All.
3. Choose Format > AutoFormat. The Add button is now active.
4. Click Add.
5. In the Name box of the Add AutoFormat dialog, type a meaningful name for the new format.
6. Click OK to save. The new format is now available in the Format list in the AutoFormat dialog.

Comment: Which new format is made available after this? All it shows is the new AutoFormat name in the list. How to customize it? this is not given in this answer.